# "User not authorized to perform this action" when creating publisher topic

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

We are trying to create a publisher topic to provide a pub/sub channel to be notified when new messages arrive via REST.

We are using two C# API V 1.35.1 and Google PubSub V 1.0 Beta 20.

**This works if we are registering the pub/sub for a developer account. But if we try to  with a standard account it fails.**

To create the topic we have these methods.

```
 public PublisherServiceApiClient GetPublisher()
 {
            GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(GmailCredentials.Token.AccessToken);
            Channel channel = new Channel(PublisherServiceApiClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
                PublisherServiceApiClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, cred.ToChannelCredentials());

            var settings = PublisherServiceApiSettings.GetDefault();
            return PublisherServiceApiClient.Create(channel, settings);
}

public Topic CreateTopic()
{ 
            var publisherService = GetPublisher();

            var topicName = new TopicName(GmailProjectId, GMailVenueTopic);
            Topic topic = publisherService.CreateTopic(topicName);
            return topic;
```

}

The failure occurs at:

```
publisherService.CreateTopic(topicName);
```

with the exception

```
Grp.Core.RpcExcetion
```

and message:

```
“Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail="User not authorized to perform this action.")”
```

These are the permissions requested at the time we logged in through oauth using the gmail authentication api.

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
```

These are the scopes that are added

```
public string GmailScopes => "https://mail.google.com/ " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels " +
 "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts" +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group " +                                     
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly " +
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform " +
 "profile " + "email";
```

Q: Is there a missing scope that's required when we're using a standard account, not a developers account?

Q: Could this somehow be related to the C# API being in beta?

Note: These are additional comments ------------------------------------------

Let me explain what we are trying to do.  To be sure that the approach we have taken is compatible with what the Gmail API provides?

Currently, we have a server application that has this workflow:

- Asks a mobile device to get their oauth token and sends it to our
  server.
- Create a thread where our server connects via IMAP using    the
  mobiles oauth token.
- Uses the imap idle() to listen for new email events.

We are  trying to replace this design, with a REST Based approach.  We don’t want to spawn 100’s of threads each with an open sockets to IMAP.

From your answers we believe we would be required to do the following:

- From the projects owners account, add each customer’s account to our
  IAM with the role of Pub/Sub Subscriber
- From the end-users account, Login to gmail-api using the OAuth
  credentials and call “watch” every day to keep the subscription
  active.

The problems with this approach is:

- We are creating a SAS application. The users are not members of our
  organization.
- All of the user accounts will need to be added to our organization
  IAM with the role of Pub/Sub Subscriber
- We don’t see any api’s to allow us to add users to our IAM, we must
  go through the console.

Not sure were we are going wrong here. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Its saying the user doesn't have access.   The issue is with the user not with the scope.

Comment: Have you checked and compared the permissions between both user accounts? It really looks, as @DaImTo said, an IAM issue.

Comment: I updated the original post with more comments.. Thanks again!

Comment: @dalmto The problems with this approach is:

1) We are creating a SAS application. The users are not members of our organization.
2) All of the user accounts will need to be added to our organization IAM with the role of Pub/Sub Subscriber

Comment: You don't want to be adding end users to your IAM roles - these are for developers or administrators that work directly with the project. It looks to me like you'd need a different approach, where'd you likely need to create an API of some kind - it's beyond the scope here, but I'd recommend looking at [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/) to start

Comment: @ChristopherP Please review this link to see my current thinking about his problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977023/gmail-api-monitor-for-new-email-for-sas-application-where-users-are-not-part-o

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to push message to Google Pub/Sub. I solved the issue by adding `Pub/Sub Admin` role to a member in `IAM` section.